# Set custom Add to cart default quantity except on Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I'm using this filter below to to set default quantity of 2 products to be predefined when adding to cart by default. It actually works on product page and defaults quantity setting to 2 and adds 2 products to Cart. But the problem appears when user comes to Cart page, if he/she added 4 products, all the calculations are done correctly EXCEPT displayed quantity is 2. Even if I change quantity on Cart page to 6 for example, and refresh Cart, all the amounts are recalculated correctly except displayed quantity is shown as 2.
I figure I should somehow apply this filter to Add to cart button only, but don't know how.

I'd appriciate the help.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'rb_woocommerce_quantity_changes', 10, 2 );
function rb_woocommerce_quantity_changes( $args, $product ) {
   $args['input_value'] = 2;
   $args['max_value'] = 12;
   $args['min_value'] = 1;
   $args['step'] = 1;
   return $args; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following using `is_cart()` on `'input_value'` argument:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {

   if( ! is_cart() ) {
       $args['input_value'] = 2; // Not on cart page
   }
   $args['max_value'] = 12;
   $args['min_value'] = 1;
   $args['step'] = 1;

   return $args; 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related documentation: [Woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for this explanation LoicTheAztec. I needed this condition `! is_cart`. Could you please point me in the direction where I can find all those definitions alla is_cart etc?

Comment: @Wed Added the documentation link in the answer

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec, do this auto add all products which current are not in the cart in to the cart ? For example,  if product 1 already added to cart with 4 as quantity, it should not overwrite the product 1 with 2 quantity, correct ?

Comment: @Maxfield I don't catch, sorry.

Comment: I undeleteded a question which has more detail, can you please take a look.